# Dimensionality reduction by minimizing the spread between data points

Tags: python, data-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a three-dimensional point dataset (please refer to the images) which has an underlying structure, as seen in Image [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20dM.png). My goal is to classify these independent "data pillars". My foolish approach would be to rotate the dataset in all axis and compute a statistical measure of spread and choose subsequently the projection on which this measure is minimized and then perform a cluster analysis.

Now to my question: Is there a way to do this analytically? The dimensionality-reduction algorithms I ran into always want to preserve the structure or maximize the variance in the dataset, but is there an algorithm that would fit my application case?

If you have a hint and want to share it here, it would be very appreciated by me.

Thankfully,
Jakob Krieger

[image: Second view]
[image: Wanted view]
[image: First view]
[image: Third view]

Comment: My first thought would be to round off the X and/or Y values in a separate attribute on each data point, then used those rounded values to group the separate "columns". I.e. if one cluster is around -40, one around -20, and one at +20, you could use a tolerance of about 9.5 to group all points within 9.5 units either side of each cluster point.

Comment: I think if you're trying to do [clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_cluster_comparison.html), spectral methods will pick up on this kind of structure quite easily.  If your datasets are 3-dimensional and separable like this though, why not just do it by eye?

Comment: @CharlesAngus That's not possible because this would mean that data pillars which have the same latitude would be grouped together. @stevemo I tried clustering (using `sklearn`), but my data never was clustered along the inclined axis, which is shared by the wanted clusters. The dataset is only a possible user input, so doing it by eye is unfortunately not an option.